# Does Jdeveloper 12 support creating Swing applications?

Tags: java, swing, jdeveloper

There is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_2/jdtut_11r2_2.html) at Oracle for creating a Swing application in Jdeveloper 11, but when I tried to follow that in Jdeveloper 12 there was no 'Java application' under 'Swing/AWT' branch of gallery. Is JD12 no longer supporting Swing apps or the process has changed?

Answer (score 1):

It bills itself as `a free integrated development environment that simplifies the development of Java-based SOA and Java EE applications`

so I guess your answer would be, no, they aren't helping you make Swing-based applications.  But that doesn't mean you can't, J2SE has all you (basically) need for Swing and you'd have to write against it anyway.

Comment: Uh, ok your words are marked.  I'm not a jdeveloper guy I'm just trying to help a brother out.

Answer (score 1):

JDeveloper 12c support Swing development - in fact it includes new features for Swing development including the Matisse layout from NetBeans.
Create a new application of type "Java Desktop Application" and you'll see the wizards that you need to visually build Swing in JDeveloper. It's under "Client Tier" category.

Comment: What was the purpose of changing the gallery since 11? To confuse everyone?